# C# Winforms how to get text from Datagridview to a label based on another cell on the same row?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm looking for an answer to the following:

Here is my DataGridView:
[DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flD3c.png)

The imported data updates every 5 minutes, which changes the row count and order. How can I get the data of one cell based on another cell which is on the same row?

E.g. in the picture, I want to get the "raw_text" cell to be displayed on a label. To get that correct cell, I need to check that "station_id" is "AGGH", and then get all info from that row to different labels.

I have tried this:

```
labelmetar.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells["raw_text"].Value as string;
```

but the rows keep changing all the time, so it's not possible. Instead of row number (`.Rows[1]`...), it should ask "row where station_id equals AGGH". How can I do that?

Any advice?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (dgvRow.Cells["station_id"].Value.ToString() == "AGGH")
                {
                    string rawText = dgvRow.Cells["raw_text"].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```